# Python socket programming , how to communicate with another computer in the same network

Tags: python, sockets, multiplayer

#SOLVED#
It is solved when i disable Microsoft FireWall...

I want to make a basic multiplayer game using **pygame and socket**.

I created two scripts server.py and client.py .

I can send data from one pythonwindow to anotherwindow in the same computer but **I want to send data to another window in another computer that connects the same internet connection**.

How could it be possible ? Thank you

**server.py**

```
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ipv4 = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 1233

server_socket.bind((ipv4, port))
#Listens for new connections.
server_socket.listen(5)
#5 is backlog parameter that means while server is busy keep 5 connections.
# If sixth connection comes it will immediately be refused.

connection = True
while connection:
    print("Server is waiting for connection.")
    client_socket,addr = server_socket.accept()
    print("client connected from {}".format(addr))
    while True:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        #Max 1024 bytes can be received and the max amount of bytes is given as parameter.
        if not data or data.decode("utf-8") == "END":
            connection = False
            break
        print("received from client : {a}".format(a = data.decode("utf-8")))
        try:
            client_socket.send(bytes("Hey client","utf-8"))
        except:
            print("Exited by the user")
    client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ipv4 = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 1233
print(ipv4)

#Connection of client to the server.
client_socket.connect((ipv4, port))

message = "Hey naber moruk nasilsin? Ben gayet iyiyim."

try :
    while True:
        client_socket.send(message.encode("utf-8"))
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)
        print(str(data))
        more = input("Want to send more data to the server ? ('yes' or 'no')")
        if more.lower() == "y":
            message = input("Enter Payload")
        else:
            break
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Exited by the user")

client_socket.close()
```

Comment: You have to connect to the IP address of the other computer instead of the IP address of your own computer.

Comment: RIght.  In the client, you need `ipv4 = socket.gethostbyname("myservercomputer")`.

Comment: Thank the both of you so much for your effort . I did it but it didn't work . I realized its why ... As I learn , I forgot to deactivate my Microsoft Firewall...